# Expand a element to fill li

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to expand the `a` elements of this jsfiddle to fill the `li` element, but `display:block` does not work as I'm using a table to space them.

How can this be done in order for my colored corners to work? As I've got a background set on both `a` and the `li` elements to give the illusion of colored corners.

http://jsfiddle.net/286bu/

Comment: What look are you trying to achieve? You want the corners under the rounded corners to be a different color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `height` parameter to your `a` tag so it fills the entire height of the `li`:

```
.menu a {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not quite work because the line height is not tall enough to show all the text for some of the 3-line links.  There is another CSS rule further down the page that is constraining the height... namely `ul.slider li {height: 20px;}`